# Multiple component with same state name, change one without affection others onclick on parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, I will try to make this quick, when I click on the div with the className "question" I want my icon to change from angle-up to angle-down and vice versa (also want to make another div visible / invisible). Things is, im currently using this.state.icon, so when I click on one question all the icon change for all the other too (same for the . Here is my code :

```
class FAQ extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state={
        showMe:true,
        icon:"angle-down"
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log(prevState);
}

getReveal(event) {
    this.setState({
        showMe:!this.state.showMe,
        icon: this.state.icon === "angle-up" ? "angle-down" : "angle-up"
    })
}

render() {
    const { menu } = this.props;
    return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.category}>
                    <h2>Cat</h2>
                    <div className={styles.question}>
                        <p>Question 1 ?<FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.iconAngle} icon={this.state.icon} /></p>
                    </div>
                    {
                        this.state.showMe?
                    <div className={styles.answer}>
                        <h3 className={styles.titleAnswer}>Title 1</h3>
                        <p>Answer 1 </p>
                    </div>
                    :null
                    }</div>

                    <div className={styles.question} onClick={this.getReveal.bind(this)}>
                        <p>Question 2 ?<FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.iconAngle} icon={this.state.icon} /></p>
                    </div>
                    {
                        this.state.showMe?
                    <div className={styles.answer}>
                        <h3 className={styles.titleAnswer}>title 2</h3>
                        <p>Answer 2 </p>
                    </div>
                    :null
                    }</div>
    );
}
```

So, my question is, how can I change the icon and reveal the answer only for the question I click on ?

Thanks in advance for any help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by keeping questions as a separate component and then maintaining their own state. Currently all the questions are governed by a single state parameter and therefore toggling show/hide for single question impacts all other.If you keep each question in its own component and maintain the show/hide state there, then you would be able to manage each question's state independently. Hope this helps.